# Components issue on extending custom AppController class

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a custom structure in my CakePHP app which goes like this:

```
class AppController extends Controller // default

class ExtendedAppController extends AppController

class ChildController extends ExtendedAppController
```

The components I declare in *ExtendedAppController* get erased when I declare components in a *ChildController* class. I guess I will have this same problem with helpers also. How do I merge the arrays to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake merges the current controller's variables with only **ONE** parent class which by default is set in the variable `$_mergeParent = 'AppController';` in the core `Controller` class.

You can override this variable in your ChildController by defining:

```
class ChildController extends ExtendedAppController {

    protected $_mergeParent = 'ExtendedAppController';

}
```

However, this will ignore all the helpers and components defined in AppController, so copy  the components and helpers from your AppController to your ExtendedAppController. This should answer your question I guess as you will be able to use ExtendedAppController's components from your ChildController and other controllers extending AppController will use AppController's components.

It is the way the Controller::_mergeControllerVars() method is written in the core. This is precisely why the [book says](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#components-helpers-and-uses):

> The HtmlHelper, FormHelper, and SessionHelper are available by
>   default, as is the SessionComponent. **But if you choose to define your
>   own $helpers array in AppController, make sure to include HtmlHelper
>   and FormHelper** if you want them still available by default in your
>   Controllers.

Comment: I got it working. Took me a while because `$_mergeParent` should be a string, not an array. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry about that! I was experimenting a lot myself to see if I could pass an array and copy pasted that wrong code that didn't work, rather than the one that did. Obviously, $_mergeParent needs to be a string as it is passed to the is_subclass_of() method which throws an error if an array is passed.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. When I have to work on it, I will remember it better :).